# How do I add inline-css during hook_css_alter()?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a use-case where I need to dynamically attach inline-CSS (and JS) at runtime.

In `hook_css_alter()` I cannot see how to attach it and I keep ending up with:

> Exception: Invalid CSS asset type. in Drupal\Core\Asset\CssCollectionRenderer->render() (line 216 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/CssCollectionRenderer.php).

I have tried this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
function MODULE_css_alter(&$css, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  $inline = MODULE_get_inline_css();
  $css[$inline] = [
    'type' => 'inline',
  ];
}
```

I have managed to get code into the `html_head` section, but I need this to appear after the styles section.

(This is for migrating the add_to_head module)

Comment: Use hook_page_attachments_alter instead(+ define libraries) + inline type no longer exists(i think).

Comment: I use attachment alter for HEAD. But I could not see how to append to styles/scripts in there. If I alter the #attached part, it just broke the CSS/JS on the page and left the placeholder token un-replaced.

Comment: I think it is only possible in the theme layer.

Comment: Your hook implementation never adds any CSS.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - the $inline value is the inline CSS to be added. This was the way it worked in D7 (https://api.drupal.org/comment/22683#comment-22683) so clearly the API has changed in D8... hence the question :)

Comment: Yes, but look at your code. Where are you using `$inline`?

Comment: Typo - it's meant to be the key on the array. I'll update it. Good catch ;)